# How to remove cancel button from inbuilt UI of startActivity (intent),

Tags: windows, android-studio

[This image came after startActivity (intent)][1]
I am installing downloaded APK file
And I got this inbuilt UI after startActivity (intent)
And I am not able to remove cancel button.
It will be very grateful , please help me out

below is my code part:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(APK_FULL_PATH)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The installation happens outside of your app, unless you have a manufacturer certificate.